# Print Composer does not show Item Options

Tags: print-composer

I'm rather new to QGIS, the version I have is 3.16.
I want to create a print layout, but when I open the Print Composer panel **the "Item Options" window is empty**. No way to choose the size of paper or anything else that should be inside that window.

I looked around, both on QGIS and on internet but found no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add some items to be able to set options for them. For example add a map.

You set Page size by right-clicking the blank canvas then select Page Properties.

[image]